# How to Show Previous Year on Dynamic Date

Tags: sql, date, view, union-all

I have a database that has customer, product, date and volume/revenue data.  I'd like to create two NEW columns to show the previous year volume and revenue based on the date/customer/product.

I've tried unioning two views, one that has dates (unchanged) and a second view that creates a CTE where I select the dates minus one year with another select statement off of that where VOL and REV are renamed VOL_PY and REV_PY but the data is incomplete. Basically what's happening is the PY data is only pulling volume and revenue if there is data in the prior year (for example if a customer didn't sell a product in 2021 but DID in 2020, it wouldn't pull for the VOL_PY for 2020 - because it didn't sell in 2021).  How do I get my code to include matches in dates but also the instances where there isn't data in the "current" year?

Here's what I'm going for:
[EXAMPLE DATA WITH NEW COLUMNS]

[image: 1]

CURRENT YEAR VIEW:

```
   SELECT
   CUSTOMER
  ,PRODUCT
  ,DATE
  ,VOL
  ,REV
  ,0 AS VOL_HL_PY
  ,0 AS REV_DOLS_PY
  ,DATEADD(YEAR, -1, DATE) AS DATE_PY FROM dbo.vwReporting
```

PREVIOUS YEAR VIEW:

```
WITH CTE_PYFIGURES 
     ([AUTONUMBER]
      ,CUSTOMER
      ,PRODUCT
      ,DATE
      ,VOL
      ,REV
      ,DATE_PY
      ) AS 

(
SELECT b.*
     , DATEADD(YEAR, 1, DATE) AS DATE_PY
FROM dbo.basetable b
)

SELECT  
       v.CUSTOMER
      ,v.PRODUCT
      ,v.DATE
      ,0 AS v.VOL
      ,0 AS v.REV
      ,CTE.VOL_HL AS VOL_HL_PY
      ,CTE.REV_DOLS AS REV_DOLS_PY
      ,DATEADD(YEAR,-1,CTE.PERIOD_DATE_PY) AS PERIOD_DATE_PY
FROM dbo.vwReporting AS v
FULL OUTER JOIN CTE_PYFIGURES AS CTE ON CTE.CUSTOMER=V.CUSTOMER AND CTE.PRODUCT=V.PRODCUT AND CTE.DATE_PY=V.DATE
```

Comment: Do union of two datasets where zeroes should be mapped to corresponding measures (to `PY` measures in current year part and to current year's measures in previous year part) and then aggregate them

Comment: Add a tag for database you are using. Sample dat should be posted as text table, not image.

Comment: I would create a query that will show values per year and then I would do left join with the same query except the year will be year + 1 in the left join statement. Imagine you will combine 2021 with 2020 + 1 then and thus get the perfect results and furthermore it will be simple!

Answer (score 1):

You need to offset your current year's data to one year forward and then union it with the current data, placing zeroes for "other" measures (`VOL` and `REV` for previous year and `VOL_PY` and `REV_PY` for current year). Then do aggregation. This way you'll have all the dimensions' values that were in current or previous year.

```
with a as (
  select
    CUSTOMER
    , PRODUCT
    , [DATE]
    , VOL
    , REV
    , 0 as vol_py
    , 0 as rev_py
  from dbo.vwReporting

  union all

  select
    CUSTOMER
    , PRODUCT
    , dateadd(year, 1, [DATE]) as [DATE]
    , 0 as VOL
    , 0 as REV
    , vol as vol_py
    , rev as rev_py
  from dbo.vwReporting
)
select
    CUSTOMER
    , PRODUCT
    , [DATE]
    , VOL
    , sum(vol) as vol
    , sum(rev) as rev
    , sum(vol_py) as vol_py
    , sum(rev_py) as rev_py
from a
group by
    CUSTOMER
    , PRODUCT
    , [DATE]
    , VOL
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  This solved my problem, I really appreciate your help.